# Internal Error building a FireBReath Plugin with XCODE 4.2

Tags: xcode, macos, npapi, firebreath

Hello recently I reinstalled my mac os x machine I have the following configuration:
1. Mac Os x Snow Leopard 10.6.8 
2. Xcode 4.2 (4C199) for snow leopard with sdk 10.6
3. Firebreath project 1.6
4. CMAKE 2.8-8

I have created a plugIn test project,after run the prepmac.sh command everything is built ok. last I open it with XCODE and start the Build process.

after a 10 minutes a Crash error is generated in the process.

A message appears: Internal Error, XCODE encountered an internal logic error.

```
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-   928/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/Target.subproj/PBXTarget.m:4146
Details:  target 'azTest' has been asked for its build context but it does not belong to a project
Object:   <PBXNativeTarget: 0x200f62f00>
Method:   -targetBuildContext
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x2019f6fa0>{name = (null), num = 25}
Hints:   None

    Backtrace:
  0  0x00000001009e6646 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x000000010006aaa4 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x0000000116655973 -[PBXTarget targetBuildContext] (in DevToolsCore)
  3  0x000000011665908d -[PBXTarget(XCBuildables) buildDidFinishWithBuildLogRecorder:] (in DevToolsCore)
  4  0x00000001167e0222 -[Xcode3TargetBuildableSnapshot buildForBuilderDidFinish:] (in DevToolsCore)
  5  0x000000010068997a -[IDEBuildableSnapshot performBuildForBuilder:buildCommand:buildOnlyTheseFiles:] (in IDEFoundation)
  6  0x00000001005c3753 -[IDEBuilder main] (in IDEFoundation)
  7  0x00007fff83a75dd0 -[__NSOperationInternal start] (in Foundation)
  8  0x00007fff83b53bd5 ____NSOQSchedule_block_invoke_2 (in Foundation)
  9  0x00007fff81d47d64 _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libSystem.B.dylib)
 10  0x00007fff81d262d1 _dispatch_worker_thread2 (in libSystem.B.dylib)
 11  0x00007fff81d25c08 _pthread_wqthread (in libSystem.B.dylib)
 12  0x00007fff81d25aa5 start_wqthread (in libSystem.B.dylib)

 if  I choose continue XCODE Finally crash with this detail:


objc[2341]: garbage collection is ON
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object at objects[0]'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8628a784 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff80bd1f03 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff862344d7 -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 407
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff862408e1 +[NSArray arrayWithObject:] + 49
    4   DevToolsCore                        0x000000011663a72e -[PBXTarget filePathForBuildableProductFileMapForWorkspaceArenaSnapshot:] + 79
    5   DevToolsCore                        0x000000011664f0b7 -[PBXTarget(XCBuildables) buildDidFinishWithBuildLogRecorder:] + 79
    6   DevToolsCore                        0x00000001167d6222 -[Xcode3TargetBuildableSnapshot buildForBuilderDidFinish:] + 99
    7   IDEFoundation                       0x000000010068997a -[IDEBuildableSnapshot performBuildForBuilder:buildCommand:buildOnlyTheseFiles:] + 1397
    8   IDEFoundation                       0x00000001005c3753 -[IDEBuilder main] + 1136
    9   Foundation                          0x00007fff83a75dd0 -[__NSOperationInternal start] + 681
    10  Foundation                          0x00007fff83b53bd5 ____NSOQSchedule_block_invoke_2 + 129
    11  libSystem.B.dylib                   0x00007fff81d47d64 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
    12  libSystem.B.dylib                   0x00007fff81d262d1 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 239
    13  libSystem.B.dylib                   0x00007fff81d25c08 _pthread_wqthread + 353
    14  libSystem.B.dylib                   0x00007fff81d25aa5 start_wqthread + 13
)
```

I can't get that the Building process works fine. So I decided to post here looking for help.
I have to mention that I tested the same project in another machine with MAC OS X Lion and it worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

This is less of an answer and more of a workaround; XCode 4 seems to use a ridiculously large amount of memory on any project that uses boost which includes FireBreath projects.  try building from the command line with:

```
cmake --build path/to/build/
```

See if that works.